# Using php display one array contain the key with the values that contain another array

Tags: php, arrays

Display one array with key and the value should be another array(key and value)

Example:

```
<?php
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");
?>

<pre><?php print_r($a1); ?></pre>
<pre><?php print_r($a2); ?></pre>
```

In the above example I want to display  the array (a2) should be displayed in the value of array(a1) with the key "a".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Please use the provided `edit` link below your question to further refine the text you posted.

Comment: Show us what you have tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what you actually ask, but I would give this answer as a "long shot":

```
<?php
$a1 = ["a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue", "d"=>"yellow"];
$a2 = ["e"=>"red", "f"=>"green", "g"=>"blue"];
$a1["a"] = $a2;
?>
<pre><?php print_r($a1); ?></pre>
```

You obviously can shorten this into a more direct and readable style:

```
<?php
$a1 = [
    "a" => [
        "e"=>"red", 
        "f"=>"green", 
        "g"=>"blue"
    ], 
    "b" => "green", 
    "c" => "blue", 
    "d" => "yellow"
];
<pre><?php print_r($a1); ?></pre>
```

---

As it turned out in the confusing discussion in the comments below you are actually looking for a way to implode that second array into a comma separated list, so a single string... Here is a solution for that:

```
<?php
$a1 = ["a"=>"red", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue", "d"=>"yellow"];
$a2 = ["e"=>"red", "f"=>"green", "g"=>"blue"];
$a1["a"] = implode(',', $a2);
?>
<pre><?php print_r($a1); ?></pre>
```

Comment: You answered coorectly what i am expecting...Thank you

Comment: But i want in tha "$a1" array the key "a" contain entire array of "$a2" but i want only the values of "$a2" inside the "a" key.

Comment: Then please explain how a single variable (or array element) should contain multiple values at the same time, if not by using an array.

Comment: y its possible that the key contain more values.

Comment: I asked "how", not "if". A variable can only contain one single value at a time. not multiple.

Comment: $a1 = ["a"=>"red,blue", "b"=>"green", "c"=>"blue", "d"=>"yellow"];

Comment: Good god. So you are talking about a colon separated list, so a string. In that case the variable _does_ contain only a _single_ value, the string `"red,blue"`. That are _not_ multiple values from a technical point of view.

Comment: I added a solution for that.

Comment: so then how can i get the values of array 1 in the key of array 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125691/discussion-between-arkascha-and-karthiga).